# Which version of Nginx Ingress Controller is recommend for Kubernetes 1.17

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using Kubernetes 1.17.9 on bare metal, try to install Nginx Ingress Controller.

I've checked [Kubernetes doc](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), [Github doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), and [Nginx doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/releases/), haven't find any information about which version of Nginx Ingress Controller should been use for which version of Kubernetes.

Is there any pages for that?

Answer (score 2):

As per [releases page](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/releases/) the newest version is NGINX Ingress Controller 1.8.1 with NGINX version to 1.19.2 on board.

On the [NGINX Ingress Controller Technical Specifications](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/technical-specifications/#supported-kubernetes-versions) you can find info that current NGINX Ingress Controller release has been verified to run on the following Kubernetes versions:

```
Kubernetes 1.14-1.18
```

Ans also the way you can check is look through [NGINX Ingress Controller Helm Chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/nginx/nginx-ingress).

For example,

[0.2.1 chart version](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/nginx/nginx-ingress/0.2.1) sais you it contains 1.4.6 NGINX Ingress Controller and you need Kubernetes 1.6+

[latest 0.6.1 version](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/nginx/nginx-ingress/0.6.1) contains 1.8.1 NGINX Ingress Controller and you need Kubernetes 1.14-1.18

Advice you use latest one

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm looking for. I notice that ([the page](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/technical-specifications/#supported-kubernetes-versions)) been referred didn't say the old releases of Nginx Ingress Controller correspond to which Kubernetes versions. It will be better if that kind of page exist.

Comment: And currently I'm using manifest, so helm can't help. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped. But upvote better than thanks here))

Comment: @se681268 [thats explanation why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: This answer is hardly complete. There are HEAPS of different versions from different companies that are all still being updated. There is an "official" version at kubernetes/ingress-nginx, and bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller are also very well respected. The companies that make the actual software are not necessarily the best ones to package something for Kubernetes... This doesn't really answer the question properly.